# How to redirect with Heroku / Amazon cloudfront / route 53

Tags: heroku, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am hosting single page application on heroku and use amazon cloudfront, route 53 for it. Now I would like to redirect some internal routes into other route without touching the source code.

For example

```
http://example.com/foo -> http://example.com/bar
```

Is it possible with some cloudfront or route 53 configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways.

**Lambda@Edge:**

You can create a lambda edge function for viewer request and perform the redirect.

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /*
     * Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
     */
    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: 'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html',
            }],
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

**Reference:**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html

**API-Gateway:**

Create a http proxy and perform the redirect to desired url.
You also need to create origin and associate the behaviour from cloudfront to this api-gateway endpoint.

**API-Gateway with Lambda:**

Pass the url to API-Gateway with **ANY** integration and that gets to Lambda, you can return response for the same.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var response = {
        statusCode: 301,
        headers: {
            "Location" : "https://example.com"
        },
        body: null
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Hope it helps.